# Why in ARCH/GARCH model we don't add residual?

Tags: volatility, garch

The most simple ARCH is given by:

$$\sigma^2_t=E{\epsilon_t^2|I_{t-1}}=\alpha_0+\alpha_1\epsilon^2_{t-1}$$

Why in this model we do not have residual as well? Example:

$$\sigma^2_t=E{\epsilon_t^2|I_{t-1}}=\alpha_0+\alpha_1\epsilon^2_{t-1}+u_t$$

Answer (score 2):

In general, a (G)ARCH model can be written as:
\begin{align}
r_t&=\mu_t+\epsilon_t \\
\epsilon_t &=\sigma_t u_t \, ,u_t \overset{iid}{\sim}(0,1)
\end{align}
Where $\mu_t=E(r_t\vert {\cal F}_{t-1})$ is the expected value of $r_t$ given the information set ${\cal F}_{t-1}$ and $\epsilon_t$ is the error term. $\mu_t$ is used to model dynamics of the mean. Dependencies in the second moments are modeled by using the variance equation, i.e., the functional form of $\sigma_t^2$. One key characteristic of all (G)ARCH models is that $\sigma_t^2$ is specified as a deterministic function of past
returns (or other variables), that are known at time $t$, given ${\cal F}_{t-1}$.

If you would include a random variable $v_t$ in the variance equation, you get a **stochastic volatility model**. In this case, $\sigma_t^2$ depends on an unobservable innovation and hence $\sigma_t^2$ itself is an inherently unobservable, i.e., a latent random
variable. Hence, $\sigma_t^2$ is not measurable w.r.t. observable past returns.

What seems to be a small difference, has far reaching results:

1. The introduction of the separate innovation substantially increases the flexibility of the model in describing the volatility dynamics, but it also increases the overall difficulty of the model.
2. Since, conditional on ${\cal F}_{t-1}$,  $\sigma_t^2$ is non-random in GARCH models, these models can be estimated via ML. In contrast to this, stochastic volatility models cannot be estimated via ML and you need to apply more complex estimation techniques like GMM or MCMC. In my opinion, this is one of the main reasons why (G)ARCH models are so popular (at least in academia).

Comment: ML is Maximum Likelihood not the other ML ;)

Comment: $\sigma_t^2$ (as a value or as a function of the past) is not observable in GARCH models. I think your intension is correct, but a more appropriate word is needed. Also, the mean equation is not $\mu_t$ (which is just the conditional mean) but $r_t=\mu_t+\epsilon_t$ as it expresses $r_t$ via an additive decomposition of the conditional mean $\mu_t$ and a zero-mean residual $\epsilon_t$.

Comment: @RichardHardy I edited my answer. I think it is now more understandable.

Comment: You still have *as an observable deterministic function*.

Comment: Yep, I removed the "observable" part. thx